# cURL doesn't return all levels of JSON with variable in URL

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to consume an API with PHP 7.1.6. When I send the request with the API key hard-coded into the URL, it returns all the JSON. But, when I put the API key into the URL through a variable. It only returns the first level of JSON. I have tried setting the URL as a variable, then making the variable `$url` a cURL option and I've tried having the string with double and single quotes. Is there something else I can try to get it to work?

Also, I know the problem is with the actually response itself, but with `json_decode()` because when I look at the raw response, not all the JSON that should be there is present. The API key is just letters and number and when I copy the concatenated URL into Postman from the debugger, it works as it should

Here is the request:

```
$curl = curl_init();

  curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => '/collection?fields=collection_id,name,description,f_list,modified_at&api_key=' . $api_key,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE     => $this->cookie,
  CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR      => $this->cookie,
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: Break this problem down into pieces.  Compare the URL as-concatenated to what it is in the string.  I don't know what your API key is, but make sure you're using `url_encode()` to escape it properly for use in the URL.  In any case, this question has absolutely nothing to do with cURL.  It's going to come down to simple concatenation.

Comment: I have. When I copy the concatenated URL from the debugger and run the request in Postman, it works perfectly fine. I've copied the cURL code from Postman for the request, still when I include the API key as a variable, it doesn't return all levels of JSON. The API key is just letters and numbers.

Comment: Re-check your assumptions.  If you had showed enough code to reproduce it, I'm sure we could quickly point out your typographical error.

Comment: The issue was parsing of the string, though not the API key. Rather, it was one of the parameters I've left off due to its length. That parameter needed to be formatted as JSON, but rather than escaping the double quotes, I had to encode them as you said.